# Why does `du` on a device reports zero usage?

Tags: command-line, disk-usage

Output of

```
sudo df -h
```

is

```
Filesystem                                              Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
rootfs                                                  9.2G  5.7G  3.1G  65% /
udev                                                     10M     0   10M   0% /dev
tmpfs                                                   357M  720K  356M   1% /run
/dev/disk/by-uuid/13605893-3936-4fd6-a7f5-e249f16c3f72  9.2G  5.7G  3.1G  65% /
tmpfs                                                   5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs                                                   2.2G  2.5M  2.2G   1% /run/shm
/dev/sda6 

                                          278G   12G  252G   5% /home
```

whereas

```
sudo du -sh /dev/sd*
```

gives

```
0   /dev/sda
0   /dev/sda1
0   /dev/sda2
0   /dev/sda5
0   /dev/sda6
```

o_O

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your raw devices are listed in `/dev/`, but that's not where the file system lives. Once the device is mounted it's available in the *mount point*, as listed in the "Mounted on" column.

You should run `du` on or somewhere in a mount point to count the usage on the file system. E.g.:

```
sudo du -sh /home
```

What you were doing is asking how much space the device listing is using in the virtual file system `/dev`. This is nothing, as it's purely virtual.

Answer (score 2):

A device like `/dev/sda` is a special kind of file that can be used to access some kernel functions. You can create devices using [mknod](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/mknod.1.html).

`du` treats devices just like any other file and shows the size they are using in the file system which is always 0.

Answer (score 2):

I stumbled upon this old thread and for anyone looking for a solution to list the file sizes when "du" gives a 0 size output on a mounted virtual filesystem, just add the "-b" flag. Like so:

```
du -sbh <path>
```

The following will also work (which is included in the "-b" flag):

```
du -sh --apparent-size <path>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well there is a known difference between the free space shown by `df` vs the amount of drive space minus the space used in `du` (because of block sizes and overheads and things like that), but that's not what you're asking here...

`du` works on mounted filesystems. You're trying to get it to work on devices and partitions. If you want to see what the space on a free particular device, loop through its partitions, mount them and then run `du` with its `--one-file-system` (aka `-x`) argument.

Eg:

```
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
sudo du -shx /mnt/
sudo umount /mnt/
# repeat for sda2, sdb1, etc
```